# Jquery: Why is delay not working?

Tags: jquery

I added a delay but it is not working...

```
<div id="sum"></div>рублей​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
$('#sum').html('3000').delay(3000).html('5000');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jv8g6/

Why is delay not working?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only affects the animation queue, and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) does not use that queue.

However, you can call [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and invoke `html()` from its callback function to achieve the effect you want:

```
$("#sum").html("3000").delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).html("5000").dequeue();
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv8g6/3/).

Comment: Thanks for the development of my knowledge )

Answer (score 2):

`delay()` applies to actions stored in the queue - such as animations. `html()` does not use the queue, therefore the code above does not behave as you expect.

For non-queued actions, you will need to use `setTimeout()` to delay execution. Try this:

```
$('#sum').html('3000');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#sum').html('5000');
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Is there any list that tells you delay() compatibility?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh not that I've found, but the rule of thumb is any method that uses animation: eg `slideUp()`, `slideDown()`, `animate()` and any function you've added using `queue()`.